# Check if Cell value exists in Row, and return a value in the same Column but different Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

For instance i need to check The first instance where the **value lies in range "B3:AY3"**, and **return it's corresponding value from Row 2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions to do this, e.g. if lookup value is in A1 this formula will find the first A1 value in B3:AY3 and return the corresponding value from row 2

`=INDEX(B$2:AY$2,MATCH(A1,B3:AY3,0))`

Comment: Thanks mate, however i don't have the specific value to Match it can be any value(Integer, Letter)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean - can you give an example?